# du very slow on NTFS disk

Tags: linux, disk-usage, ntfs

Just doing a simple `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h` took 71 minutes (measured by `time`).

I have tested disk IO with `dd`; write speed 135 MB/s, and read speed 6,9 GB/s.
I am using this command on a folder of `rsnapshot` backups; total file size is 30GB, which is approximately the same of my system. If I run `du -h --max-depth=1 | sort -h` (with `--exclude` of the NTFS disk, of course) it takes around 3 seconds.

The disk is mounted in fstab as:

```
UUID=C6560CA5560C97F7   /media/pc/extdisk   ntfs    permissions 0   2
```

`du` result on NTFS disk with `time`:

```
101M    ./daily.4
101M    ./daily.5
102M    ./daily.1
102M    ./daily.2
102M    ./daily.6
265M    ./daily.3
29G ./daily.0
30G .

real    71m30.353s
user    0m14.399s
sys 1m55.442s
```

I'm guessing it is because `rsnapshot` creates hardlinks, and that slows down (a lot)?
I just ran the same command on a normal folder and it took 7 seconds for 6GB.

Comment: NOt sure but almost sure that the fact ntfs is not a unix/linux file system it way less efficient when working with command such as `du`

Comment: Are you using the ntfs module built into the kernel or the third-party ntfs-3g?